# Android - How do you bind a ListView to a collection of custom objects?

Tags: android, data-binding, listview

I've got a class called `PhoneContact` with 3 properties:
*Title*, *Description* and *PhoneNumber*

If I have a collection of these, how would I go about binding these to a `ListView` containing a `TextView` for each property?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Extend `ArrayAdapter`, overriding the `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)`.

To hook up your custom adapter, I'll assume your `Activity` extends `ListActivity`. In one of the lifecycle methods (such as `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, or `onStart()`), call `setListAdapter(myCustomAdapter)`.

This article shows how to do it: Android Series: [Custom ListView items and adapters](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/).

Comment: I'd just been going through that page when you answered, exactly what I was after. Thanks!