# Is there a way where we can get data from a webpage using jsoup and display it as a listview in android?

Tags: android, jsoup

I am trying to get a list of data from a webpage using Jsoup and want ot to be displayed as a list view  in my android application. I have got the data but I am unable to set it in the list view.

I have got the data from the web page and have stored it in a string builder as I am unable to store it in a list view.

```
public class BollywoodFragment extends Fragment {

ListView bollyList;
TextView text1;
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String>arrayAdapter;

StringBuilder bollyMovies = new StringBuilder();

public BollywoodFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bollywood, container, false);
    text1= (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    bollyList = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.bollyList);

    new bolly().execute("https://right2see.home.blog/bollywood/");
    return view;
}
class bolly extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
    String words;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {
            String url = "https://right2see.home.blog/bollywood/";
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            Elements elements = document.select("div.post-content.clear");
            for(Element element:elements){
                bollyMovies.append(element.getElementsByTag("a").text());
            }

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        text1.setText(bollyMovies);
    }
}
```

}

The above code is displaying the correct output in a text view. But I want that output in a list view, is there a way I can do that?

Comment: You're half way there. Create the list view and then bind the collection of data to the list view -- that should be it.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318313/android-how-do-you-bind-a-listview-to-a-collection-of-custom-objects

Comment: instead of adding everything into the stringbuilder, add each *list item* into the list, and then set that list as source of your ListView

Answer (score 0):

You can create `Movie` objects and then bind them to the `ListView`

You can read more here: [Android - How do you bind a ListView to a collection of custom objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318313/android-how-do-you-bind-a-listview-to-a-collection-of-custom-objects)

You're almost there -- you just have to do the data binding piece. You could use strings as well if you just have to show this and that's it.